# JAXB / JAX-RS Collection binding - without annotation

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

I'm working on a JAX-RS WebService receiving XML data such as:

```
<movie>
  <id>ID</id>
  <genres>
    <genre>horror</genre>
    <genre>scifi</genre>
  </genres>
</movie>
```

This needs to be bind to a POJO that I cannot annotate (coming from a separate jar) that look like that:

```
public class Movie {
    private String id;
    private List<Genre> genres;
    // ... usual getter/setters
}
```

My JAX-RS entry point:

```
@PUT
@Path("/movies")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response put(JAXBElement<Movie> movieWrapper) {
    Movie movie = movieWrapper.getValue();
    //...;
}
```

The XML data is processed successfully, but only the 'id' attribute get properly setted. The field 'genres' is 'null'.

How can I have JAXB properly process the collection's content ?

NB: There is many numerous blogs/articles on how to achieve this with annotations, but sadly in this case, I can't change the POJO itself.

Comment: Please, add `Genre` pojo. Can you modify request structure?

Comment: JAXB is configuration by exception, so annotations are only required when you want to override default behaviour you should be able to do with POJOs with out any annotations. There must be something wrong with your Genre Class. JAXBElement<Movie> movieWrapper = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Movie.class); try this and see if there is an exception.